# How do I search filenames for specific text in iOS

Tags: ios, file, search

My iPad app stores thousands of files in it's directory, and I'd like to be able to search these files.  How would I go about doing this?  I realize I probably can't search the contents of the files, but just being able to search the filenames would be nice.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), particularly the [`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) or [`enumeratorAtPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtPath%3a) methods, to get the list of filenames and then process them however you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Using it, you can get the contents of a directory:

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

and even get the contents of a file:

```
- (NSData *)contentsAtPath:(NSString *)path
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can search your files: Have a look at [Full-text search with Cocoa](http://vafer.org/blog/20090107014544/). It discusses two approaches: LuceneKit and sqlite.